# Can you add null terminators to a C++11 string and iterate over them?

Tags: c++11

In C++11, is it legal to put null terminators in a C++11 string and then iterate over the entire length of the string?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   std::string s("\0\0hello\0world\n");

   for (char c : s) {
       std::cout << " " << (unsigned int)c;
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: [yes](https://ideone.com/WNNox2)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, but you need to tell the constructor how many characters you are passing. Otherwise, the constructor will try determining the length by searching for null terminator (i.e. the way the `strlen` does it), and it is going to get a wrong answer.

```
std::string s("\0\0hello\0world\n", 14);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/WNNox2)